# jQuery consumes a JSON JAX-WS web service

Tags: json, web-services, jquery, jax-ws

I tried to utilize jQuery to consume a JSON JAX-WS web service, using [JAX-WS RI for JSON](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/jaxws_ri_extens.html)

I tried to follow their instruction, but can't make a call from javascript client to JAX-WS web service, although the web service was built successfully.

Here is my code:

Server side:

```
@BindingType(JSONBindingID.JSON_BINDING)    
@WebService 
public class Greeting
{       
    public Book get(@WebParam(name="id") int id) {
        Book b = new Book();
        b.id = id;
        return b;
    }

    public static final class Book {
        public int id = 1;
        public String title = "Java";
    }

}
```

Client side:

```
<header>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/webservice/soap/greeting?js"> </script>
    $(document).ready(function()  {
        $("#btnJson1").click(function() {
             document.getElementById("jsonprompt").innerHTML="Start JSON --- ";
             GreetingService.get(
              {id:5},
              function(r) {
                  document.getElementById("jsonprompt").innerHTML="Book Title: " + r.title;
                  }
            );
    } );
</header>
```

Any comment or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

If there's any solution to consume a JAX-WS service using jQuery over JSON will be highly appreciated too.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Error log on Firebug: GreetingService is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions for my problem.

The 1st one is using XMLHttpRequest in javascript at client side (this is not really related to jQuery), and make a "POST" call into JSON server as I mentioned on my question.

The 2nd one is as following.

At server side, I make a JSON JAX-WS web service using library [JAX-WS JSON web service](http://code.google.com/p/jsonwebservice/wiki/GettingStarted)

```
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService (name="SchedulerService", targetNamespace="http://my.target.namespace.vn/json/")
public class Scheduler
{
    @WebMethod
    public Book get(@WebParam(name="id") int id) {
        Book b = new Book();
        b.id = id;
        return b;
    }
    public static final class Book {
        public int id = 1;
        public String title = "Java";
    }

}
```

On client side, just make a json call like this using jQuery library.

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
    $("#btnJson").click(function() {
    alert("Start JSON --- ");
    $.post( "http://localhost:8080/webservice/json/scheduler",
            '{"get":{"id":5}}', 
              function(r) {
            alert("Book Title: " + r['return'].title);
            }, 
            "json" ) ; 
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. In your answer you've got a SOAPBinding, but you're talking about using JSON.

Comment: I just want to implement a Jax-ws web service that support JSON call from jQuery, and fortunately that this solution solve my problem.

Do you have any suggestion? That will be highly appreciated.